# Mysqli php i want a custom error message when unknown server host

Tags: php, error-handling, mysqli, warnings, config

I am writing a script to install the database of an application in php. It working fine but when im trying to install a database that doesnt exist i want only my own error message but i keep getting the default Warning : Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'kasdasd'.

So I know that the host is wrong and I want it to be so, with only my own errormessage. How do I get rid of this message?

My connectclass with parameter DBConfig $config:

```
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($config->m_host,
                                $config->m_user,
                                $config->m_passw,
                                $config->m_db);

    if ($this->mysqli->connect_error) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

    return true;
```

Comment: Don't do that. @ hides errors, which is bad. It also doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an easy solution would be to see if you can open the hostname using fsockopen and suppressing the errors:

```
$port = 80;

if($fp = @fsockopen($config->m_host,$port)){
    $db = new mysqli($config->m_host,$config->m_user,$config->m_passw,$config->m_db);
}else{
    echo 'hostname not recognized';
}
@fclose($fp);
```

Comment: nice one, but port 80? not every mysql server runs http

Comment: i suppose that he only write 80 cause i dont ask the user for the port. if i do so the user can decide himself :) thx!

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

You can use

```
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    /** handle your error here **/
    // Throw a custom exception if you like! (see below)
    // or just echo "There was an error";
}
```

You can further use `mysqli_connect_errno()` to find out wht happened and handle it accordingly.

**Edit: mysqli doesn't throw erros so below is incorrect.**

Wrap your code in a try-catch, then you can throw whatever kind of error you like:

```
try {
  /** your code here **/
} catch (Exception $e) {
  /** your handling here **/
  // i.e.
  throw new BadHostNameException($config->m_host);
  // or
  echo "Could not connect!":
}
```

Note: you should replace `Exception $e` with the specific kind of exception a bad host throws so `catch(MysqlBadHostnameException $e)` (the type of error will be in your error log from your previous attempts or you can do `get_class($e)` in my example above.

// Isusing a custom exception: Add this outside of your class..

```
class BadHostNameException extends Exception {}
```

Comment: Does mysqli throw an exception when connection fails?

Comment: +1 Ugh, nope. No wonder the push to get people to use PDO., I'll amend answer (thanks for heads up)

Comment: yeah but the thing is i return false and in my other codes i check if it returns false im doing the errormessage. so i get the errormessage but also the warning..